# How come I can't upgrade my google analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to upgrade my google analytics account to universal analytics. In the admin-panel in google analytics there is suppose to be a button in the property–column, but there isn't. When I'm looking at the tracking code, it suggests that I use ga.js, suggesting that I still use the old version of google analytics. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be that they haven't enabled it for your account, or you have doubleclick support enabled on your profile -- if that is checked, then you won't see the Upgrade.

Comment: I have double-click support enabled and use the dc.js file. I used to experiment with remarketing, but don't any more. Can I disable doubleclick somehow?

Comment: Yeah, to disabled simple toggle it to off. Does the code on your site still contain dc.js? Not sure how to tell Google that you want to have your property "migrateable" - try googling it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a premium account?  Google Analytics doesn't support the new tracking on premium accounts.

Source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

I've just recently encountered this issue. It seems as though today they've made it available and taken it out of beta. Try logging into your Account> Property >Admin and you should see the option to begin the transfer.